# How can I declare a lambda property once for re-use?

Tags: c#, lambda, signalr

I have this code in my startup class...

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<RouteUpdate>("/routeupdate"); });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseAzureSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<RouteUpdate>("/routeupdate"); });
            }
```

I've also tried doing this.

```
        var routesCollection = new ServiceRouteBuilder(routes =>
       {
            routes.MapHub<RouteUpdate>(nameof(RouteUpdate));
       });
```

Which doesn't work...

How can I re-use the same collection and reference it once?  I have googled "lambda variable re-use" and equivalent and I can't see a way forward.

Comment: It'll be something like `Action<Routes> x = routes => { routes.MapHub<RouteUpdate>("/routeupdate"); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.signalrappbuilderextensions.usesignalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2) you can see the parameter type is `Action<HubRouteBuilder>`. This is what you need to build in order to be able to re-use it.

```
Action<HubRouteBuilder> routeAction = routes => { routes.MapHub<RouteUpdate>("/routeupdate"); };

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSignalR(routeAction);
}
else
{
    app.UseAzureSignalR(routeAction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to supply an `Action<HubRouteBuilder>` (which is a delegate type that basically describes a "method that takes a `HubRouteBuilder` and returns void") you can define a method or local function and reference it later:

```
void configureRoute(HubRouteBuilder routes) 
    => routes.MapHub<RouteUpdate>("/routeupdate");

if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseSignalR(configureRoute);
else
    app.UseAzureSignalR(configureRoute);
```